# MODX git workflow

Tags: git, modx

I want to know what is the best way to develop a website in MODX but using GIT in team.

How I understand everything, MODX saves the template, chunk, snippets and also other stuff directly to the DB and if a Team member who works on the same project, makes changes inside MODX manager those changes can't be pushed to git so easily.

How do you guys solve this problem? Is there some other way except dumping and replacing the database every time when there are changes made?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just set your elements to static files and clear the remote site's cache when you merge up? https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/static-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about Gitify? It is a great tool for git workflow with MODX. 
It makes possible to save any MODX object (snippets, templates, lexicons, custom classes) to file and revert it back when needed. You can see more here: http://modmore.github.io/Gitify/

Comment: if there is some video tutorial how to do this it would be nice if you could post the link.

Comment: I went through the docs, but I don't get it how does the data from my local DB gets written to my team developers DB?

Comment: https://video.modmore.com/modx-weekend-2014/sunday-backend/staging-workflow-with-git-and-gitify/

Comment: you:
1) gitify extract

Comment: 2) git add _data/
3) git commit -m 'commit message'
4) git push

Comment: your colleagues:
1) git pull
2) gitify build

Comment: unfortunately the repo seems unmaintained... are there any alternatives?!

Answer (score 0):

For chunks, templates, snippets plugins etc I always use static elements.

https://docs.modx.com/3.x/en/building-sites/elements/static-elements

This means you can manage your code in and your git workflow.

I also use an extra called ElementHelper. This watches for any new files you add and creates the relevant element in the database which saves you a lot of time linking up static elements and moves all my development outside of the manager.

https://github.com/roryg/ElementHelper